# Can you combine keyword argument expansion with regular keyword arguments?

Tags: python, splat, keyword-expansion

What I want to do is this:

```
logged_in = {
    'logged_in': True,
    'username' : 'myself',
    }
print render_template('/path/to/template.html',
    **logged_in,
    title = 'My page title',
    more  = 'even more stuff',
    )
```

But that doesn't work. Is there any way to combine a dictionary expansion with explicit arguments, or would I need to define the explicit arguments in second dictionary, merge the two, and expand the result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Keyword expansion must be at the end.

```
print render_template('/path/to/template.html',
    title = 'My page title',
    more  = 'even more stuff',
    **logged_in
)
```

Comment: I actually tried this before posting and it didn't work. You made me revisit it, and it turns out you're not allowed to put a comma after the last argument if it's an expansion.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you just have it backwards. The keyword expansion must be at the end.

```
def foo(a,b,c,d):
   print [a,b,c,d]

kwargs = {'b':2,'c':3}
foo(1,d=4,**kwargs)
# prints [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

The above work because they are in proper order, which is unnamed arguments, named, then keyword expansion (while the `*` expression can go either before or after the named arguments but not after the keyword expansion). If you were to do these, however, it would be a syntax error:

```
 foo(1,**kwargs,d=4)
 foo(d=4,**kwargs,1)
 foo(d=4,1,**kwargs)
```